# Read Thyristor(Triac) specification

Tags: pcb, components, triac, thyristor, component-values

I have this Triac which I believe is failed because of a hight current we had in the house. The varistors that were next to it were totally burned.

I am trying to buy some online, but I really don't know how to narrow the specifications.

How do I read its specification?

Here is what you see in the picture.

BTA06-600CW
GK072  VU
CHN  233

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried looking for the datasheet yet?

Comment: http://www.st.com/en/thyristors-scr-and-ac-switches/bta06.html

Comment: If varistors failed, you had over-voltage. Your triac is BTA06-600CW. But look for BTA06 and number behind dash at least 600 (this is blocking voltage, so 800 is even better) :) Look for CW it means 35mA snuberless, it may be important depending of the actual circuit.

Comment: Here is the datasheet: http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/d8/82/66/ee/67/5b/4e/7f/CD00000670.pdf/files/CD00000670.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000670.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your varistor is **BTA06-600CW**.

Look for **BTA06** and number behind dash at least 600 (this is blocking voltage, so 800 is even better) :)

Also **CW** is important as it means 35mA snuberless, it may be important depending of the actual circuit.

[datasheet](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/d8/82/66/ee/67/5b/4e/7f/CD00000670.pdf/files/CD00000670.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000670.pdf)

EDIT:
Or simple:
Buy either **BTA06-600CW** or **BTA06-800CW**

Comment: ok, I found this one BTA06-600CWRG. Is it still ok if it has other number after CW?

Comment: Yes, that is fine. Extra letters are not important for you. You have explanation of every letter on page 5 of datasheet.